# Moving to next column every click automatically in VBA

Tags: vba, calculated-columns

I want to go to the next column each time I click on a button. I have tried this but it does not work:

```
Dim i As Integer
If i = 0 Then
i = 4
End If
i = i + 1
ffc = ActiveCell.Offset(x, i).Column
```

I used `ffc` because I want to add it to other button to insert the value "A" or "P" like this:

```
Sheet3.Cells(x, ffc).Value = "A"
```

To understand more, my project is for record attendance by days. My problem is just moving to the next column.
I have tried this too

```
ffc = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row
```

It works but it's working with rows, which mean when I go down in rows the column move one step and I want the column move when I only press the button

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Columns.Count
   ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Select
Next
```

Comment: Hello Praveen, thanks for your answer but unfortunately that's not working, it's take me to the last column while I want it to move just one step to next column

Comment: Please Try this. 
Dim i, n As Integer
    n = InputBox("Enter no of columns to be moved")
    For i = 1 To n
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Select
    Next